# VLOOKUP with wildcard and find Nth occurance?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm setting up a Google Sheet that will calculate the most effective purchase size of specific agricultural inputs (fertilizer, chemical, etc). I set up the price data in its own tab with a separate row for each input name + size.

To keep it easy for the user I'd like to require only the input name, # of gallons per acre, and acres and then have a formula spit out the total cost and most effective purchase (bulk if > X gallons, X # of 250 gallon containers + X 55 drums, etc). How can I use the input name plus a wildcard to find the appropriate purchase size?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMOPuk2qhmVuJT7vE_ni3KFxfcgKvwTwkM4p50xQF_0/edit?usp=sharing

I tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(INDEX('Data (Current)'!H2:H,SMALL(IF($A2&"*"='Data (Current)'!A2:A,ROW('Data (Current)'!A2:A)-1),1))))
```

...but it returns blank so I'm guessing the reference `$A2&"*"` to the input name isn't working properly. When I replace it with a string found in the 'Data (Current)' tab then it works fine.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(INDEX('Data (Current)'!H2:H,SMALL(IF($A2&"*"='Data (Current)'!A2:A,ROW('Data (Current)'!A2:A)-1),1))))
```

I expected the output to be the smallest value (in this case I think it's `5`). Then when I change the last number to `2` or `3` it will find the next smallest value, in this case, `55` or `250`. Then I can use simple formulas to interact with that and finish the spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, the actual output is nothing, or `""`.

Comment: arrayformula does not like index fx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for, as I had some trouble understanding your question.

Presuming what you want is essentially this:

> I want to buy *Y* quantity of *item*.
>
> I can buy *item* at cheaper prices if I buy in higher quantities, although sometimes they have a minimum order quantity.
>
> What is the most optimal combination of the options I have to minimize the price I pay?

I'm unsure if there's a simple solution for this within Google Sheets alone. This might be treading more into Apps Script territory.

However, that's not to say that it's not impossible. I've "brute-forced" the above solution above with an iterative-like approach, for the "Chelated Calcium" product: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YSBiSx0IMr4T0R11Dqb-tqOhH4AOTTAWeH2yQfT4X5w

1. First, list the data in a standardized manner. This includes giving each same product something easy to look it up by. For example, on the **Data (Current)** tab, I've added 3 columns:

   - Product Common Name - This is used so that all items of different quantities can be found easily, without needing wildcards.
   - Gallons - Much easier to parse the data if it it's explicitly laid out.
   - Minimum Order Gallons - This is your threshold for Bulk. I've set it at an arbitrary 20,000 gallons for Chelated Calcium.
2. The data here is ordered **least-effective** first. How you do this will be up to you. In this case, I sorted by the *Retail Cost Per Ounce* parameter from your sheet, highest first. This eliminates any guesswork about which of the options are most effective, since you can just traverse your options in order. **Note: The way I've laid out the formulas will only work IFF the same products are directly next to each other. It won't work if there are other products between them.**
3. On the **Field Level Tool** tab, standardize your inputs to the Gallons unit. I do this in *Total Gallons Needed* column (I multiply anything with a "GAL" with 1, and "QUART" with 0.25).
4. For each item, determine the row numbers where the product begins and ends. This is marked by columns L (*Least Efficient Index*) and M (*Most Efficient Index*). I got these results by using the `MATCH` function.
5. Set up the iterations, from 0 to *N-1*. On this sheet, I've set up *N=5* iterations, which means that it can traverse 5 different options of the same product only. Since Chelated Calcium only has 4 different options (5 Gal, 30 Gal, 250 Gal, Bulk), 5 is more than enough for this product. If you have products with more options, you may want to have more iterations.

   - The iterations are on the right side of the **Field Level Tool** tab.
   - In your case, you might want to put it on a different tab since the place I put it makes the file look very messy.
6. In each iteration, I perform the following steps:

   - *To Fulfill* - How many gallons still need to be purchased by this iteration?
   - *ThisIndex* - What is the row number of this iteration? This is determined by *Most Efficient Index* - *Iteration Number*. Remember that since we sorted in order of ascending efficiency, this means that the iteration starts with the most efficient option it can find first. There is a check to make sure that it only outputs a value if it is between the range [*Least Efficient Index*, *Most Efficient Index*]. Otherwise, it will be blank to avoid miscalculations by intruding into another product in the **Data (Current)** tab.
   - *Retail Price*, *Minimum Gals*, *Gallons per Order* - Simple data extraction for easy usage in the iteration, using `INDEX` (and indirectly, `MATCH` by virtue of *ThisIndex*).
   - *Order* - This formula does a couple of things, outlined below:

     - It checks whether there still remains a valid choice of product at this iteration. It does this by checking whether *ThisIndex* still exists. If the product doesn't exist, then it will be nulled. This is accomplished by using the `IF` function.
     - It will determine if there is a minimum threshold that must be met to purchase this choice. You can see in the 0th iteration, for example, that there is a minimum quantity of 20,000 gallons. If *To Fulfill* quantity is greater than or equal to the threshold OR there is no threshold, then a purchase is quantified by this column. The mathematics are simply to divide the *To Fulfill* amount by the *Gallons per Order* amount to determine the number of orders of this particular product choice. If there is a threshold but the *To Fulfill* amount doesn't meet it, then this iteration is skipped with a *0* order value.
     - If the item is already on its least efficient choice (*ThisIndex* == *Least Efficient Index*), it will do a `CEILING` function to ensure that the order is fulfilled. If not, it will do a `FLOOR` function instead. This is because you cannot order 3.5 units of an item, so they have to be rounded either up or down.
   - *Expenditure* - This is simply *Order* multiplied by the *Retail Price*, or how much money you spend in this iteration.
   - *Remaining* - How much of the product is left unfulfilled at the end of this iteration, to be used as *To Fulfill* for the next iteration.
   - Note: If you see formulas that are of the form `=IF(ThisIndex, [calculations_here],)`, that is simply a check to nullify that calculation if *ThisIndex* is invalid.
7. Copy the iterations as many times as you want to the right. Something nice to do is to force the iterations to do a `CEILING` on the very last one to ensure that you never under-buy.
8. Generate a user-readable string for the purchase suggestion. You can see this on the *Suggested Purchase* column.
9. Calculate the *Gallons Bought* with a simple `SUMPRODUCT` over all the iterations.
10. Calculate the total expenditure with a simple `SUM` over all the iterations.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Regardless, it's at least a fun exercise on how much you can abuse Sheets. ;)